# .C# Unit Test environment with complete run dump for replay purposes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dump

Is there a tool that would allow me to record the complete environment setup including all local variable values when a unit test is run?

My problem is that I have a couple of unit tests that are not deterministic, in such sense that at the startup some variables are assigned random values.
What I noticed is that a particular test is correct 95% of the time, but fails in those 5% which is hard to catch.

It would be nice to have a tool/test environment that would to replay the particular test method in case it fails.  Of course assigning random values would have to be skipped and replaced with recorded values.

Maybe it is too hard to achieve. So my second question is is there a nice test framework with good log capabilities (stack trace recording in case of exception, assertion fails, etc.) that would allow me to analyze errors in described scenario. Or maybe the tools I am using now, have such features but I am not aware of them.

What tools I use now:
Visual Studio 2012 Premium edition CU4 + NUnit 2.6.3 + NUnit Test Adapter 1.2 + TestDriven.NET-3.8.2860

Comment: "My problem is that I have a couple of unit tests that are not deterministic, in such sense that at the startup some variables are assigned random values. What I noticed is that a particular test is correct 95% of the time, but fails in those 5% which is hard to catch." You should eliminate these factors rather than work around them. Everything should be deterministic in a unit test - randomly generated input isn't all that important.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in this case is to pass a seed value to my Random object in my tests. This will ensure that you are generating the same 'random' data every time in the test so making them both Random and deterministic.

So where ever you are saying

```
Random random = new Random();
```

change it to

```
Random random = new Random(0);
```